# MapReduce - Secondary Sort

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to sort my reducer output in descending order, the following is my mapper/reducer output ?

Mapper output : Text, IntWritable

Reducer output:  IntWritable, Text

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493644/sort-order-with-hadoop-mapred)